# How do I pass session to new socket via fsockopen?

Tags: php, session, asynchronous, background-process, fsockopen

I need to pass the session to an asynchronous call via fsockopen in php.

Can you help me pass the session to the new socket?

**SOLUTION:**

The following code works.

**start.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var1'] = 'value1';
async_call('/async.php');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "\r\n";
echo '<a href="verify.php">verify.php</a>';

function async_call($filepath) {
    $host = 'sandbox'; // set to your domain
    $sock = fsockopen($host, 80);
    fwrite($sock, "GET $filepath HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fwrite($sock, "Host: $host\r\n");
    fwrite($sock, "Cookie: PHPSESSID=" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "\r\n");
    fwrite($sock, "Connection: close\r\n");
    fwrite($sock, "\r\n");
    fflush($sock);
    fclose($sock);
}
?>
```

**async.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
logger('confirm logger is working');
logger($_SESSION);  // this is always blank!

function logger($msg) {
    $filename = 'debug.log';
    $fd = fopen($filename, "a");
    if (is_array($msg))
        $msg = json_encode($msg);
    $msg = '[' . date('Y/m/d h:i:s', time()) . "]\t" . $msg;
    fwrite($fd, $msg . "\n");
    fclose($fd);
}
?>
```

**verify.php**

```
<?php
$logfile = 'debug.log';
echo '<a href="start.php">start.php</a>';
echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents($logfile);
?>
```

---

I could get this working locally, but it turned out the shared host I was staging on disallowed fsockopen without any documentation.  All good on my own servers.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm aware that phpsessid is saved as a cookie, but I'm not clear on how to retrieve it to access the session variables in my asynch script.

Comment: Check your previous question, I added a reply that should solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297827/how-can-i-run-an-fql-request-in-the-background-asynchronous-api-calls-via-php/7298224#7298224

Comment: I edited for clarity.  Andreas, you've been helpful but for some reason I'm still stuck.  Can you take a look at my simple debug scripts above to see what I'm missing?

Comment: That's because you made a mistake, or my instructions weren't 100% clear. It should be `fwrite($sock, "Cookie: PHPSESSID=" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "\r\n");`

Comment: Ahhh... got it... the async.php has to have a session_start(). I'll confirm my main script works and then update this to reflect success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help, Andreas.  Turns out the shared host I was staging on disallowed fsockopen without any documentation.  That's why I could get it working locally but not on the staging server.

The following code works.

**start.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var1'] = 'value1';
async_call('/async.php');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "\r\n";
echo '<a href="verify.php">verify.php</a>';

function async_call($filepath) {
    $host = 'sandbox'; // set to your domain
    $sock = fsockopen($host, 80);
    fwrite($sock, "GET $filepath HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fwrite($sock, "Host: $host\r\n");
    fwrite($sock, "Cookie: PHPSESSID=" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "\r\n");
    fwrite($sock, "Connection: close\r\n");
    fwrite($sock, "\r\n");
    fflush($sock);
    fclose($sock);
}
?>
```

**async.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
logger('confirm logger is working');
logger($_SESSION);  // this is always blank!

function logger($msg) {
    $filename = 'debug.log';
    $fd = fopen($filename, "a");
    if (is_array($msg))
        $msg = json_encode($msg);
    $msg = '[' . date('Y/m/d h:i:s', time()) . "]\t" . $msg;
    fwrite($fd, $msg . "\n");
    fclose($fd);
}
?>
```

**verify.php**

```
<?php
$logfile = 'debug.log';
echo '<a href="start.php">start.php</a>';
echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents($logfile);
?>
```