# PHP Asynchronous process to call facebook SDK

Tags: php, asynchronous, facebook-php-sdk

I've been messing this for far too long and would like a bit more help.

Basically a user logs in and I get there facebook data (Email, id, etc).
This alone takes around 25 seconds. 
I've work hard to reduce it to that.
Also I need to pull the friend list and avatar image.
Initially this used to take 4 minutes.
But after hard researching I got it down to around 30 secs.
So combined it takes around 50 seconds.

So I start to separate the friend list and the avatar image process to run asynchronously.

I tried using

- Ajax call: Causes user to wait for process to end. IE when attempting to move to another page it hangs until process is finished.
- exec: Does not keep facebook login data so cannot call facebook API
- fsocket: Does not seem to run asynchronously. Still take the same time.

So I'm not sure on my options.
I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300871/how-do-i-pass-session-to-new-socket-via-fsockopen) to run the socket method but I'm still getting logins at around 50 seconds. IF I remove the call to this process it reduces to just over 20.

What an I doing wrong?
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Form multiple reasons ranging from in internal features and mobile optimization I need to gather the friend list and download the images.

Ajax is called on the via

`$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
            data: data,
        cache: false,
        context: context,
    });`

And the fsocket is called via

`$host = getHost( );
        $sock = fsockopen($host, 80);
        fwrite($sock, "GET ".getRoot( )."/updatefb.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fwrite($sock, "Host: $host\r\n");
        fwrite($sock, "Cookie: PHPSESSID=" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "\r\n");
        fwrite($sock, "Connection: close\r\n");
        fwrite($sock, "\r\n");
        fflush($sock);
        fclose($sock);`

Comment: Not sure we can tell what you are doing wrong/right without seeing your code...

Comment: Well the code runs and works. But it causes the page to wait until it is finished. Which code are you referring to?

Comment: You asked `What an I doing wrong?` We can't tell what you are doing wrong (if anything) without seeing what you are actually doing? We need to see the code you are using to pull the friend list and avatar image.

Comment: Why do you need to see that code? This issue is I'm having trouble running the processes Asynchronously. Pulling the facebook data works fine. I have spent many hours optimising as best I can. This is not the issues. I need the process to run asynchronously. The reason I mention the facebook data because I must retain the users login status. This is why exec will not work. I have added in the calls to the processes above.